# on google app engine are how are StructuredProperties updated?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, datamodel

I am considering ways of organizing data for my application.

One data model I am considering would entail having entities where each entity could contain up to roughly 100 repeated StructuredProperties. The StructuredProperties would be mostly read and updated only very infrequently. My question is - if I update any of those StructuredProperties, will the entire entity get deleted from Memcache and will the entire entity be reread from the ndb? Or is it just the single StructuredProperty that will get reread? Is this any different with LocalStructuredProperty?

More generally, how are StructuredProperties organized internally? In situations where I could use multiple Float or Int properties - and I am using a StructuredProperty instead just to make my model more readable - is this a bad idea? If I am reading an entity with 100 StructuredProperties will I have to make 100 rpc calls or are the properties retrieved in bulk  as part of the original entity?

Comment: have you checked out the docs? it's all there: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#structured

Comment: I read it several times and it didn't really answer my question. But via experimenting with appstat I think I understand the situation much better now. My understanding is that if I change one of the structuredproperties the entire entity will be dropped from memcache and it will be reread from the ndb on consecutive request.

Comment: Thats is correct, and a single entity with all the StructuredProperties will be retrieved in a single rpc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StructuredProperty`s belong to the entity that contains them - so your assumption that
updating a single `StructuredProperty` will invalidate the memcache is correct.

`LocalStructuredProperty` is the same behavior - the advantage however is that each
property on a `LocalStructuredProperty` is obfuscated into a binary storage - the datastore
has no idea about the structure of a `LocalStructuredProperty`. (There is probably a deserialization
computational cost attributed to these properties - but that depends a lot on the amount
of data they contain, I imagine.)

To contrast, `StructuredProperty` actually makes its child properties available for
Query indexing in most cases - allowing you to perform complicated lookups.

Keep in mind - you should be calling `put()` for the containing entity, *not* for each
`StructuredProperty` or `LocalStructuredProperty` - so you should be seeing a single RPC
call for updating that parent entity - regardless of the number of repeated properties exist.

I would advise using `StructuredProperty` that contain `ndb.IntegerProperty(repeated=True)`, rather
than making 'parallel lists' of integers and floats - that adds more complexity to your python
model, and is exactly the behavior that `ndb.StructuredProperty` strives to replace.